# How to solve this equation by Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$$  y''+3y=\sin ^4 x ,\quad y=\frac{1}{8} +\frac{\cos2x}{2}-\frac{\cos4x}{104}.$$

Now the text book states the solution, but I don't know the process of solving this equation. I need  your help!

Comment: No,it doesn't, maybe y is a 2pi-period function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is express $\sin^4{x}$ in terms of cosines:

$$\begin{align}\sin^4{x} &= \left ( \frac{1-\cos{2 x}}{2} \right )^2\\ &= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \cos{2 x} + \frac{1}{4} \cos^2{2 x}\\ &= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \cos{2 x} + \frac{1}{4} \left (\frac{1+\cos{4 x}}{2} \right )\\ &= \frac38 - \frac{1}{2} \cos{2 x} + \frac18 \cos{4 x}\end{align}$$

Because $y'' + 3 y$ is a linear differential expression, it follows that the solution to the above equation must be a linear combination of $1$, $\cos{2 x}$, and $\cos{4 x}$:

$$y(x) = a_0 + a_2 \cos{2 x} + a_4 \cos{4 x}$$

Plug this into the differential expression:

$$y'' + 3 y = 3 a_0 - a_2 \cos{2 x} - 13 a_4 \cos{4 x} = \frac38 - \frac{1}{2} \cos{2 x} + \frac18 \cos{4 x}$$

Equating the coefficients of $1$, $\cos{2 x}$, and $\cos{4 x}$, we get the stated result.

Comment: Now you represent (sinx)^4 by triangle formula, and how can i get the fourier coefficient by by fourier formula?

Comment: @Amzoti: 1) I only showed the particular solution, I should have said that; there are no boundary conditions, so the homogeneous solution would take the form $A \cos{\sqrt{3} x} + B \sin{\sqrt{3} x}$, which is added to my particular solution. 2) Why not?  When you plug cosines and sines of certain frequencies into the diff expression, you get sines and cosines of the same certain frequencies back.  So it amounts to exactly what I did.

Comment: @parkning: what I showed you is inherently the "formula," because the cosine terms are all orthogonal to each other here.  I am not sure what you mean by triangle formula; I just applied the half-angle formula twice.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: can you solve this equation by fourier series? I means  that if you can represent (sinx)^4 by fourier fomula?

Comment: @parkning: sure I can do that - by how would you evaluate that integral?  If you are sane and competent, you will express $\sin^4$ in terms of the cosine terms I have derived, and then use orthogonality to evaluate the integrals.  Again, I did this without needing to even evaluate an integral.  This is the Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

To go along with @RonGordon's solution, we can:

1. Solve for the homogeneous solution
2. Solve using Fourier Series for the particular solution
3. Write $y = y_h + y_p$

For 1., we have:

$$m^2 + 3  = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \pm i \sqrt{3}$$

For 2., we can write the Fourier Series of $(\sin x)^4$ as:

$$\displaystyle (\sin x)^4 = \frac{3}{8} -\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 i x}-\frac{1}{4} e^{2 i x} +\frac{1}{16} e^{-4 i x}+ \frac{1}{16} e^{4 i x}$$

What you would do now, is to solve three particular solution problems (you just can easily see the forms of the exponentials):

- $\displaystyle y''+3y = \frac{3}{8}$
- $\displaystyle y''+3y = -\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 i x}-\frac{1}{4} e^{2 i x} = -\frac{1}{2} \cos 2x$
- $\displaystyle y''+3y = -\frac{1}{16} e^{-4 i x}-\frac{1}{16} e^{4 i x} = \frac{1}{8} \cos 4x$

Of course, this leads to Ron's solution for $y_p$.

For 3., we write:

$$y(x) = c_2 \sin \sqrt 3x + c_1 \cos \sqrt 3 x+\frac{1}{2} \cos 2 x - \frac{1}{104} \cos 4 x + \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: How to compute the integral a_n=\int_{-pi}^{pi}sin^4x cosnx dx

Comment: @parkning: My apologies, but I cannot read or understand what you wrote as the integral.

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti!

Comment: Yes...closures...meta on fire...mixed feelings, here too!