# How to reperesent $\sin^{4}(x)$ byFourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis

how to represent $\sin^{4}(x)$  by Fourier series?
Obviously,$\sin^{4}(x)$  is an even function, so $b_n=0$. How can i get $a_n$ ?

Comment: You can see a solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373154/how-to-solve-this-equation-by-fourier-series?noredirect=1#comment799644_373154

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin^4{x}=\left(\dfrac{1-\cos{2x}}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(1-2\cos{2x}+\cos^2{2x} \right)=\\
=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(1-2\cos{2x}+\dfrac{1+\cos{4x}}{2} \right)=\dfrac{3}{8}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos{2x}+\dfrac{1}{8}\cos{4x}$$

Comment: what i want is not this way rather than the way by fourier fomula--the way of integrating.

Comment: It is an identity, so you can simply integrate the RHS multiplied by $\cos{kx}$  .

Comment: :How to compute the integral a_n=\int_{-pi}^{pi}sin^4x cosnx dx?

Comment: $ a_k=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^4{x}\, \cos{kx}\, dx=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left(\dfrac{3}{8}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos{2x} + \dfrac{1}{8}\cos{4x}\right)\, \cos{kx}\, dx}$

Comment: I totally don't understand this. Like I thought it should look like as the infinite series.

Comment: Only three terms of Fourier series for $\sin^4{x}$ are non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sin^4 x=\frac 38 -\frac 12 \cos 2x+\frac 18\cos 4x
$$

Comment: i want to kown the process.

Comment: You can use De Moivre's formula.

Comment: This is a trig formula. You can derive it in many different ways. The easiest on is [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula)

Answer (score 0):

Without relying on the trigonometric formulas in full extent to simplify $\sin^4$, you *could try partial integration:
$$\begin{align}\int \underbrace{\sin^4x}_u\;\underbrace{\cos nx}_{v'}\;\mathrm dx &= \sin^4x\cdot\frac1n\sin nx-\frac1n\int4\sin^3x\cos x\sin nx\,\mathrm dx\end{align}.$$
Of course now you should at least make use of $2\sin x\cos x=\sin 2x$ and repeat until something nice enough remains. In the end, however, you will *always* need the formulas to convert products into sums of trig functions, so there's no argument at all against doing so right in the beginning (and getting the Fourier expansion for free, like M. Strochyk does in his solution)